# Access Populated server

Tags: webserver, firefox

I don't know if this is the write forum to post this on...  If it's not sorry to bother you!

I'm going to need to get into a server which can accept ~x users; however, ~2*x users will be trying to get in. So maybe, ~30 spaces on the server are avaliable, with ~60 users trying to get in. In order to get in, you have to keep reloading/refreshing the page.

I was wondering, do I increase my chances of getting in if I open multiple browsers, and set them to reload the page every second? i.e. would attempting to get in on multiple browsers (on the same network) increase my chances?

Also, are there any ways to increase my chances? For example, are there way to tell the server that my packets are priority or something?

By the way, I know some PHP/HTML/CSS/C++ if that makes a difference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The server limiting user connections (to X, for example) will usually accept the first X connections to be sent its way. Once one of them is finished, the server will take up on another user connection. All the old connections are either rejected or ignored (ignored, more often, to decrease load). 
Which means, if a connection has opened up, the server will accept the NEXT user connection, and not an existing one. So if you were interested in getting a connection, you would be constantly requesting user connections from the server (by constantly refreshing or opening new tabs).
HOWEVER. Trying to trick the server like this is probably not a good idea. Constantly 'bugging' the server with requests will increase the server load, which might make the existing connections take longer, and might make the server block your IP requests.
Also, take into account each browser has various optimizations, to try and improve internet connectivity. It probably won't resend a connection request every time you refresh the page, or open a new window; it might recognize an open connection exists and wait for it first, or it might use cached data. So basically, you can't effectively and consistently improve your odds at receiving a connection.

A special packet to the server might be possible if the server is configured to